# Unable to create SQL Table dynamically in c# -- "invalid column name"

Tags: c#, sql

im trying to create a table with the name of a dynamically retrieved value

here is the code

```
 string nok="";
        while (reader.Read())
            {
                noo = reader.GetInt32(3);
                nok = noo.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(noo.ToString());
            }
        con.Close();
            var commandStr = "If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = C"+nok+") CREATE TABLE C"+nok+"(A char(50),B char(50),C char(50),D char(50),E char(50),F char(50),G char(50),H char(50),I char(50),J char(50),K char(50),L char(50),M char(50),N char(50),O char(50))";
            MessageBox.Show(commandStr);   
        con.Open();    
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStr, con))
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but im getting an error invalid column name with that dynamic value

Comment: The SQL is not valid. C3 in `name = C3` should at least be enclosed in quotes (ie `name = 'C3'`).

Comment: thanks man got it
im getting incorrect syntax near that variable error
 "If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'C"+nok+"') CREATE TABLE 'C"+nok+"'(A char(50),B char(50),C char(50),D char(50),E char(50),F char(50),G char(50),H char(50),I char(50),J char(50),K char(50),L char(50),M char(50),N char(50),O char(50))";

Comment: See David's answer for your new error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't wrap the string in quotes.

When referencing the *table* as an identifier, quotes aren't needed.  Because it's an object name:

```
... CREATE TABLE C"+nok+"(A char(50), ...
```

becomes:

```
... CREATE TABLE C1(A char(50), ...
```

But when referencing the table's *name* as a *value* in the `WHERE` clause, it isn't an object identifier.  It's a column value.  The `name` column holds string values, so it needs to be compared with a string:

```
... where name = 'C"+nok+"') CREATE ...
```

becomes:

```
... where name = 'C1') CREATE ...
```

Comment: @JP1016: Glad I could help!  I didn't go into detail in my answer regarding the SQL injection vulnerability, mostly because in this *specific* case the risk seems a bit low.  (Since the value originates as an integer.)  But the risk still *exists* and I highly recommend reading up on the subject of SQL injection and how to guard against it.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the table schould be between 'name'

```
var commandStr = "If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'C"+nok+"') CREATE TABLE C"+nok+"(A char(50),B char(50),C char(50),D char(50),E char(50),F char(50),G char(50),H char(50),I char(50),J char(50),K char(50),L char(50),M char(50),N char(50),O char(50))";
```

Easier way to check if a table/object is present

```
IF OBJECT_ID('C" + nok + "') IS NULL CREATE TABLE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
select name from sysobjects where name = C"+nok+"
```

When you run this in oracle the statement executed will be:

```
select name from sysobjects where name = CWHATEVER
```

Since CWHATEVER is not in quotes it will be considered a column name instead of a string value.  For this to work it needs to be in single quotes:

```
select name from sysobjects where name = 'C"+nok+"'
```

However, this opens you up to SQL Injection.  I would strongly advise you to use [sql parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) instead.

Comment: So you tell him the wrong way to fix it in detail, but then conclude with "use SQL parameters instead?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Added a link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

The value needs single quotes around it:

```
... (select name from sysobjects where name = 'C"+nok+"') ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't just add 'nok' into your SQL statement. You need to use a parameter. Try something like this. I just took a small snippit:

```
commandStr = "if not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'c@nok')";
```

And then later, when you have the command text, replace the parameter:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nok", nok);
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL. It would work with `... where name = 'C' + @nok`

Comment: Really? I have a c# application that has something like this: `SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name = @name` and it works. That's what I used as reference. Perhaps both would work? Or is the difference that I'm not concatenating anything?

Comment: The difference is `c@nok` is sent to the SQL server for processing.  `@name` in your example is fine as it is interpreted as a query parameter. `c@nok` is interpreted as a column.

Comment: I understand. @Vulcronos explained that pretty well. Thanks for the heads up. I'll edit the answer, even though this one is not best.

Comment: @SimonBelanger What is the `c@param` called? I am trying to find information on this as I have not seen this before.

Comment: @TyCobb here is a quick [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for you.

Comment: Thanks. I think I made a flaw in thinking that `c@param` was special and not just "give me the value 'C' plus my parameter". D'OH